# javascript sqlite sql searches

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova

This function finds records ok, but the else block for "not found" isn't triggered. What am I doing wrong here?

```
/////////////////////////////
function SearchBale() {
/////////////////////////////

var baledate = $('#exBaleDate').val();


  db.transaction(function(transaction)    
  {  
    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM BaleRecords WHERE BaleDate ='" + baledate + "';",[],
        function(transaction, result)    
           { 
                if (result !== null && result.rows !== null) 
                   { var row = result.rows.item(0);
                      alert(row.BaleDate);           
                   }
                  else
                   { 
                     alert("no records found"); 
                   }

            }, errorHandler)
  }, errorHandler, nullHandler);

  return;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (result.rows.length>0) { 
    var row = result.rows.item(0); 
    alert(row.BaleDate); 
}else { 
    alert("no records found"); 
}
```

Try this